# Trying to create a new User, cannot create new user because of profileID

Tags: user, sobject, node.js, user-profile

I am trying to create a new user inside of Salesforce using nforce. However, every time I create the user I get the error: `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION` stating `Profile ID: id value of incorrect type: 005210026VpWAAUAQ4` or I receive `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY` with a message of `invalid cross reference id.` Which message I receive depends on the value I have set for profileId, `005210026VpWAAUAQ4` causes a `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION` while `00e36000000YIZ6AAO` causes an `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY.` Any ideas on how to solve the errors and create a new user?

```
var acc = nforce.createSObject('User');
acc.set('ProfileId', '00e36000000YIZ6AAO'); // throws error here
```

Comment: That profile id is incorrect validate it by running a soql on profile

Comment: though this is valid id (profile type) but it is not from same sandbox where you are running your code. make sure you see this record using soql.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty What would that look like, I only started using the Salesforce api a few days ago, would it be similar to my other soql command: `var q = "SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username = 'swheeler@test.kanban'"`?

Comment: The query string would be e.g. `select Id from Profile where Name = 'Standard User'`.

Comment: @KeithC how am I supposed to query an Sobject before I create the Sobject? I need an Id to create the `Sobject` and I need an `Sobject` to query to get an id.

Comment: Generally, profiles are not created on the fly. Query to get the Id of the relevant profile that you have already set up in the org.

Comment: I have not used nforce, but I can see an example on how to query records using it. You need to first query profile (SF associates user to specific license using profile) as suggested by other members and associate it with user before you create it. Link to example for querying records: https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce/blob/master/examples/query.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of help from the community, I realized new users in salesforce have to be tied to a profile. Unfortunately, I was not aware profiles and users were different objects in Salesforce.

My Solution:

```
var q = "SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Test_Profile'";

org.query({
            query: q
        }, function(err, resp) {
            var acc = nforce.createSObject('User');
            acc.set('ProfileId', resp.records[0]._fields.id);

            org.insert({
                sobject: acc
            }, function(err, resp) {
                if (!err) 
                    console.log('It worked!');
                else
                    console.log(err);
            });

        });
```